# Syntax error, invalid AssignmentOperator

Tags: java

```
  public void run()//This line is fine
  {
    OpenCrate.this.results.put(p, Integer.valueOf(((Integer)OpenCrate.this.results.get(p)).intValue() + 1));//This line is fine
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)//This line is fine
    {
      ItemStack it = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, (short)(new Random().nextInt(15) + 1));//This line is fine
      m = it.getItemMeta();//This line is fine
      m.setDisplayName(" ");//This line is fine
      it.setItemMeta(m);//This line is fine
      inv.setItem(i, it);//This line is fine
    }
    List<String> longlist = new ArrayList();//This line is fine
    String s;//This line is fine
    int i;//This line is fine
    for (ItemMeta m = CrateResult.getResults().iterator(); m.hasNext();//This line is fine
            i < new CrateResult(s).getChance()); //THE ERROR IS THE "<" ON THIS LINE
    {
      s = (String)m.next(); //This line is fine
      i = 0; continue;//This line is fine
      longlist.add(s);//This line is fine
      i++;//This line is fine
    }
```

I get an error on the symbol "<" that says Syntax error on token "<", invalid AssignmentOperator. This is a Bukkit Plugin.

Comment: What does `new CrateResult(s).getChance()` return? Does it return an int? Also the loop content doesn't make any sense. You always set `i = 0` and then continue. The lines after `continue` are never executed.

Answer (score 0):

The [syntax for the `for` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) is

```
for ([assignment]; [condition]; [increment action]){}
```

The syntax error is telling you that your increment action is actually a comparison, and isn't valid here.  I can't follow what you're trying to achieve with `i` in this bit, but I think you want either:

```
for (ItemMeta m = CrateResult.getResults().iterator(); i = new CrateResult(s).getChance();m.hasNext()) 
        { ...
```

Or:

```
for (ItemMeta m = CrateResult.getResults().iterator(); i < new CrateResult(s).getChance() && m.hasNext() ; ) 
        { ...
```

(Although in either case I'm not sure creating and discarding a new `CrateResults` is quite what you're after?)

Please note too that the semicolon at the end of that line in your code will cause you a problem - it will mean the `for` loop isn't actually executing any code.